# Show Last Viewed date in a View

Tags: list, list-view, object-model

I understand enabling Auditing at a Content Type or Document Library level allows you to run reports to determine when documents are opened or downloaded (last viewed). Is there a way to show this "last viewed" date in a View? For example, I want to create a View that shows documents who have not been viewed in over 1 year.  This is SharePoint 2010.  If this is not possible OOB - can it be achieved using SharePoint Object Model?  Though, the preferred is OOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/2bafb26f-fc7e-424f-bd35-fbdd70756ecb)